# C# WinMobile - How to check if TabPage was clicked or switched by other means?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm creating an application in WinMobile 6.5, and includes a form with four tabs and a grid on two of them, I'm having a weird behavior, when I scroll the horizontal bar to see all the records in the grid, when I reach the end, it automatically switches to the next tab, if I scroll all the way to the left, it switches to the next tab to the right and viceversa, this only happens in WinMobile 6.5, as I have tried in WinMobile 6.1 with no problems.

My question is, is there any way to check if the tab was changed by clicking it or by any other means? I've been trying attaching a Click Event to each TabPage, but it never gets fired. I also tried to look for the Selecting Event that would allow me to do something before the TabPage gets switched, but I cannot find it using .NET Framework 3.5. I would appreciate your help, thank you!